# postsActions.js:20 POST http://localhost:5000/api/posts 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, api, react-redux

I am trying to make a post request to send data to my rails api.  My proxy in package.json is "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/", but I am getting this error: POST http://localhost:5000/api/posts 422 (Unprocessable Entity).  I want to go to http://localhost:3001/api/posts which when I go to in the browser shows the posts json

```js
export function addPost(post, history) {
  return function(dispatch){
    dispatch({type: 'LOADING'})
    return fetch("/api/posts", {
      credentials: "include",
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        'Accept': "application/json",
        'Content-Type': "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(post)
    })
      .then(res => {
        return res.json()
      }).then(post => {
        dispatch({type: 'ADD_POST', payload: post})
        history.push('/posts')
    })
  }
}
```

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { addPost } from '../actions/postsActions';

class AddPost extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      title: "",
    }
  }

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.addPost({post: this.state}, this.props.history)
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({title: e.target.value});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Title:
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <input type="submit" value="Add Post"/>
      </form> <br/>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect(null, {addPost})(AddPost);
```

```js
 class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render(
        status: 200,
        json: Post.all
      )
  end

  def create
    post = Post.new(post_params)
    post.save ? (render json: post) : (render json: {message: post.errors}, status: 400)
  end

  private
    def post_params
      params.require(:post).permit(:title)
    end

end
```

```js
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :title, presence: true


end
```

```js
web: cd client && npm start
api: bundle exec rails s -p 3001
```

Comment: You're probably not sending a CSRF token.

Comment: Where is the Rails code?